# Why two Uni V3 pools have different bytecodes?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

I am trying to assess if two smart contracts (address_1 and address_2) are both Uni V3 pools using web3.

My idea was to request each contract's runtime bytecode as follows:

```
sc_i_bytecode = w3.eth.getCode(w3.toChecksumAddress(address_i))
```

And then compare them with the bytecode of another smart contract that I know represents a Uni V3 pool. I **do** know that both contacts at address_1 and address_2 are Uni V3 pools, but when I get their bytecodes as above they do not match (i.e. `sc_1_bytecode != sc_2_bytecode`, although both of them were implemented by the same Uni V3 factory?). They do not seem to match the bytecode of my Uni V3 reference bytecode either. I am just wondering if I am missing something and those can have indeed different bytecodes?

Comment: Can you link addresses of the two pool contracts?

Comment: E.g. 0x6c6Bc977E13Df9b0de53b251522280BB72383700 (DAI-USDC) and 0xcbcdf9626bc03e24f779434178a73a0b4bad62ed (WBTC)

Answer (score 1):

You could call the factory() method on the smart contract

https://etherscan.io/address/0xcbcdf9626bc03e24f779434178a73a0b4bad62ed#readContract

and verify that it matches the address of the v3 factory contract:
https://etherscan.io/address/0x1f98431c8ad98523631ae4a59f267346ea31f984

In your two example pools the factory() method returns the same v3 factory contract address:
0x6c6Bc977E13Df9b0de53b251522280BB72383700
0xcbcdf9626bc03e24f779434178a73a0b4bad62ed

Method from the contract code on etherscan:

```
interface IUniswapV3PoolImmutables {
    /// @notice The contract that deployed the pool, which must adhere to the IUniswapV3Factory interface
    /// @return The contract address
    function factory() external view returns (address);
```

---

As to your question of why they have different bytecodes - I'm not 100% sure. Potentially could be related to the settings? (pulled from etherscan as well)

```
{
  "optimizer": {
    "enabled": true,
    "runs": 800
  },
  "metadata": {
    "bytecodeHash": "none"
  },
  "outputSelection": {
    "*": {
      "*": [
        "evm.bytecode",
        "evm.deployedBytecode",
        "abi"
      ]
    }
  },
  "libraries": {}
}
```

Comment: Yes, you could simply call the factory method to assess if an address is a Uni V3 pool, but that would involve some extra steps compared to just comparing its ABI against a stored one for a standard Uni V3 ABI. So, again, just trying to understand why two different liq pools may have different ABIs. For context, that is not the case for Uni V2, where all pools have the same ABI.

Comment: @AdamB. the two V3 contracts you posted have the same ABI on etherscan

Copied from here 

https://etherscan.io/address/0x6c6Bc977E13Df9b0de53b251522280BB72383700#code
https://etherscan.io/address/0xcbcdf9626bc03e24f779434178a73a0b4bad62ed#code


compared here
https://text-compare.com/


These 2 V2 contracts have matching ABIs:
https://etherscan.io/address/0xb4e16d0168e52d35cacd2c6185b44281ec28c9dc#code
https://etherscan.io/address/0xa478c2975ab1ea89e8196811f51a7b7ade33eb11#code

The V2 ABIs do not match the V3 ABIs as expected

Comment: @AdamB. the contract creation code listed on etherscan for the 2 v3 contracts matches too

Comment: Sorry, I meant bytecode instead of ABI in my last comment - just like the question says.